# Two Articles reached over same menu

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I am new to Joomla and I think there must be an easy way for doing this.

I have my content-area and i want to put **two articles** there like in this pic:
[image: two articles in one Page]

The Articles should be **reached over the same menu** entry.
By now I have a simple `<jdoc:include type="component" />` for inserting main Content, but the Second "Box" should be filled with another Article.

Is this possible via Categorys ore something else?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and nastiest way to do it:

Just make one article, make some simple html code with divs or a table and paste it in the article editor (of course toggle html view first and if you have problems with code-cleanup, just deactivate the editor)

Problem Solved, you have one menu entry ;)

Otherwise you can do it with the category blog view: leading = 0, intro = 2, columns = 1, links = 0 
After that you have to style both css classes .item.column-1 and .item.column-2 to make your "article seperations"

Comment: but with one article and html we have the "client is to dumb" problem i think.  or does the tinymce editor can show me the boxed(css) like they are in the frontend?

Comment: yes it is possible to integrate the template into tinymce. google should help you out because there are enough tutorials for that ;)
but as i said you can simply stlye the blogview and set the category with those two articles to show. as above. you can use custom css classes.